# Getting highlighted text from subject in ActiveExplorer window

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro which currently copies text highlighted within the message body, but I now want to achieve the same thing when the subject title from the Explorer window is highlighted.

I'm not sure this is going to be possible, because what I'm looking for is essentially the Explorer equivalent of `Item.GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Text`, and this obviously wouldn't be an option as subject titles cannot be edited in the same way as the message body.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: Can show us your current code?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is find the HWND of the subject edit box (it is RichEdit20W control) and send the EM_GETSELTEXT message.